# Oracle 11g connection fails on oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have to do this assignment for my sql class and were using oracle sql more specifically. But when I set it up I get the ORA-12505 error. I have done research and my listener is on and everything seems to be in place and I cant tell what causes the issues.

My SQL dev. console: **https://gyazo.com/8596c3f6b38ab40258160ecbb99d0815**

My listener status: **https://gyazo.com/10cdb1d237ce914e64235103282ad865**

My tnsnames.ora:

```
XE =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-T5Q9S3P)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
 )

  EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
   )
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = PLSExtProc)
  (PRESENTATION = RO)
)
 )

  ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST = 
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
   ) 
   (CONNECT_DATA = 
  (SID = CLRExtProc) 
  (PRESENTATION = RO) 
) 
 )
```

My listner:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
     (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
   )
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
   )
 )

  LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-T5Q9S3P)(PORT = 1521))
)
 )

  DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Comment: So, you have SQL Developer. Which version of the Oracle database product do you have installed?

Comment: @BobJarvis i believe it is Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SID_NAME`'s defined are `PLSExtProc` and `CLRExtProc`. But in your SQL Dev oracle connection parameters, you are using `XE` as the `SID`, which is defined as a service_name.

Try changing the `SID` connection parameter to a valid SID, or update `XE` to use SID instead of service_name.

Also, is your SQL Developer instance running on the same machine that Oracle is installed on? If not, the HOSTNAME will also need to be updated to the actual hostname (DESKTOP-T5Q9S3P).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the XE database is not up and running. You could start up the database and retry.